# Python and aiohttp error

Tags: python

I would appreciate if some one direct me to fix the error below. I could give some hints,

1. It looks like python and aiohttp related error
2. I use ubuntu 16.04 by default it comes with python 3.5 and aiohttp 1.3.1 versions, but application recommends python 3.4 or above  and strictly aiohttp version 1.1.6
3. I don't know how to map python 3.5 with aiohttp 1.1.6

Thanks,

## GNS3 GUI version 1.4.6

```
Copyright (c) 2007-2017 GNS3 Technologies Inc. your locale en_IN.ISO8859-1 encoding is not UTF-8, switching to the UTF-8 version... 2017-02-11 22:49:48 INFO logger.py:107 Log level: INFO 2017-02-11 22:49:48 ERROR __init__.py:144 vmware command not found 2017-02-11 22:49:48 INFO servers.py:102 New local server connection http://127.0.0.1:8000 registered 2017-02-11 22:49:48 INFO
__init__.py:181 VPCS module reset 2017-02-11 22:49:48 INFO __init__.py:324 Dynamips module reset 2017-02-11 22:49:48 INFO __init__.py:264 IOU module reset 2017-02-11 22:49:48 INFO __init__.py:258 QEMU module reset 2017-02-11 22:49:48 INFO __init__.py:302 VirtualBox module reset 2017-02-11 22:49:48 INFO __init__.py:368 VMware module reset 2017-02-11 22:49:48 INFO __init__.py:70 Built-in module reset 2017-02-11 22:49:48 INFO topology.py:407 Topology reset 2017-02-11 22:49:49 INFO servers.py:530 Starting local server process with "/usr/local/bin/gns3server"
--host=127.0.0.1 --port=8000 --local --log="/home/dinesh/.config/GNS3/gns3_server.log" --pid="/home/dinesh/.config/GNS3/gns3_server.pid" Starting local server process with "/usr/local/bin/gns3server" --host=127.0.0.1
--port=8000 --local --log="/home/dinesh/.config/GNS3/gns3_server.log" --pid="/home/dinesh/.config/GNS3/gns3_server.pid" 2017-02-11 22:49:49 INFO servers.py:543 Local server process has started (PID=21616) Local server process has started (PID=21616) Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/gns3server", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gns3-server==1.4.6', 'console_scripts', 'gns3server')()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gns3_server-1.4.6-py3.5.egg/gns3server/main.py", line 71, in main
    from gns3server.run import run   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gns3_server-1.4.6-py3.5.egg/gns3server/run.py", line 31, in <module>
    from gns3server.server import Server   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gns3_server-1.4.6-py3.5.egg/gns3server/server.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .web.request_handler import RequestHandler   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gns3_server-1.4.6-py3.5.egg/gns3server/web/request_handler.py", line 22, in <module>
    class RequestHandler(aiohttp.web.RequestHandler): AttributeError: module 'aiohttp.web' has no attribute 'RequestHandler' 2017-02-11 22:50:19 CRITICAL progress_dialog.py:164 WaitForConnectionWorker thread stopping with an error: Could not connect to 127.0.0.1 on port 8000: [Errno 111] Connection refused WaitForConnectionWorker thread stopping with an error: Could not connect to 127.0.0.1 on port 8000: [Errno 111] Connection refused 2017-02-11 22:50:19 CRITICAL
__init__.py:116 Could not connect to 127.0.0.1 on port 8000: [Errno 111] Connection refused Could not connect to 127.0.0.1 on port 8000: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: Resolved installing pyhton3-aiohttp package.